# how to remove the time of the top of pdf by using Latex

Tags: pdf, latex

[image]

Hi, this is my first time to use LATEX, anyone can help me how to remove "draft of 10:19, Monday, July 24, 2017" on the top of pdf. thank in advance

Comment: If you are trying to add an image, it's still not showing. So, please fix that. Also, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151139/want-to-eliminate-the-automatic-time-stamp-of-pdflatex-or-lyx), use `\date{}` before `\maketitle`. I cite, the minimal working example from the link above:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\maketitle
test
\end{document}
```